# How to Test Private Routing with React & React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test Private Routing in my React App. I'm using the following versions:

```json
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.10",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
```

In my **PrivateRoute.js** I'm simply checking if user is logged in and redirecting accordingly:

```
...
const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
  const { component: Component, ...rest } = props;
  const user = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(matchProps) =>
        user ? <Component {...matchProps} /> : <Redirect to="/SignIn" />
      }
    />
  );
};
...
```

In my **PrivateRoute.test.js** I'm simply rendering `<PrivateRoute>` and checking the `history.location.pathname`. However, I always get `/` when expecting `/SignIn`.

```
describe("<PrivateRoute/>", () => {
  it("redirects unauthenticated users to SignIn", async () => {
    const history = createBrowserHistory();
    render(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/SomeRoute" component={SomeComponent} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );

    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe("/SignIn");
  });
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is to use `<Router history={history}>` along with `createMemoryHistory` as seen below:

This comes from [React Router Documentaiton](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/testing/checking-location-in-tests)

See example test below:

```
it("redirects unauthenticated users to SignIn", async () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory ({ initialEntries: ["/Private"] });
    const PrivateComponent = () => <>Private!</>
    const PublicComponent = () => <>Redirected!</>
    render(
        <Router history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/Private" component={PrivateComponent} />
            <Route exact path="/SignIn" component={PublicComponent} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
    expect(screen.queryByText("Private!")).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.queryByText("Redirected!")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe("/SignIn")
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason maybe is that you're redirecting the user to the SignIn component if the AuthContext isn't present. But I think the AuthContext is always present. So, you should pass a value to the context when a user logs in. And check if the value is present.

```js
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  const [loggedInUser] = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        loggedInUser.isSignedIn ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/SignIn",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

And you'll have to use the PrivateRoute component in the app.js just like you use a Route component.

```js
import React from 'react'
import PrivateRoute from 'path/to/PrivateRoute/component'

export const UserContext = createContext();

export default function App() {
const [loggedInUser, setLoggedInUser] = useState({});

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={[loggedInUser, setLoggedInUser]}>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <PrivateRoute path="/top-secret">
                        <SecretDoor></SecretDoor>
                    </PrivateRoute>
                    <Route path="/SignIn">
                        <SignIn></SignIn>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Comment: doing `<Redirect to={{ pathname: "/SignIn"...` is same as `<Redirect to="/SignIn"`, is it not? Also passing `state` object through `Redirect` doesn't appear to change anything. My test is still receiving `/` instead of `/SignIn`

Comment: Yeah, it's the same, Another reason maybe is that you'll be redirected to the SignIn component if the `AuthContext` isn't present. But I think the AuthContext is always present. So, you should pass a value to the context when a user logs in. And check if the value is present. I am updating the answer.

Comment: Yeah I already do that. My PrivateRoute works perfectly. I'm just having a problem testing it.